# CDK: Remove dependency from DependsOn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I have a CDK project which creates AWS Fargate cluster.  But it adds TaskRole and ExecutionRole automatically when I use ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService. But I am having trouble removing the FargateServiceTaskDefTaskRoleYYYYY from dependsOn.

"DependsOn": [
**"FargateServiceTaskDefTaskRoleYYYYY",**
"LoadBalancerPublicListenerECSGroupYYY23",
"LoadBalancerPublicListenerD231d"
]

Remove dependency from FragateService.

Comment: You can't remove it - it actually depends on it. Maybe clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: CDK automatically creates Execution role and task role. But these are not needed. I used the escape hatches to remove both roles but the dependsOn is not getting removed even after using escape hatches to remove execution and task roles.